# User submission/restriction

Tags: 7, forms, users

Beginner drupal user here, I know how to assign permissions to users to add/create content etc., my problem is I am trying to create a specific page where users can go to (from the main menu) to upload content whether it be images, video, etc. and the content is then displayed in its own page, for example, all images are displayed in a separate page called "images" and videos go in "videos", based on what file they uploaded. Is there a module that accomplishes this or am I just

Comment: or am I just `what`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your requirement, then you want to provide a functionality to user to upload `images` or `video` and then save the `images` or `video` respectively.

I have already implemented similar functionality in one of my recent project with following concept:

- Create a new `content type` as `upload`
- Add a list (`select`) field `Filter type` with options `image` and `video`
- Add two fields  `image` as 'image' field type
- Installed [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module and add `video` field as 'Media file selector'
- Installed [Conditional field](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module and set condition that `image` field be only visible if user select 'image' as Filter type options and `video` field be only visible if user select 'video' as Filter type options
- Set the permission to user to create content of `upload` content type.
- Now Create two views to display image and video separately.

I hope that it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Media module](https://drupal.org/project/media) for adding media (images and video) into any textarea and it (requires [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module).
After adding image and video field you can create a node containing these two fields. When you save the node using submit you will get a view of all the image and video file generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking...

> Is there a module that can look at a file upload field in a specific
>   content type, and then, based up the extension of the file uploaded,
>   sort and display the various files on separate pages?

...the answer is most probably `No.  Not out of the box anyway.`

However, the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) is quite powerful, and with a bit coding it could be done.